# How to use image carousel to go to link page in SharePoint 2013 using JQurey

Tags: jquery-ui

I am working on SharePoint 2013, there I created a Picture Lib. and I Created an Image carousel using J-Query but I want That When I click on Image it Redirect me to link Page who's URL I mention in Description Section of Image.

But When I implement it and output the value in that field, I get an

> 'Undefined`

Code which I am using to call Sp-services is as below

```
<html>

    <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
                $().SPServices({
                    operation: "GetListItems",
                    async: false,
                    listName: "Pictures",
                    CAMLRowLimit: 6,
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                        var hasRows = false;
                        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function () {
                            hasRows = true;
                            var _url = '/' + $(this).attr("ows_RequiredField")

                            var _title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                var _description = $(this).attr("ows_Description");

                            _slideDiv = $("<div class='slides_container_div'/>");
                            _link = $("<a  src='" + _url + "'/>");
                            _Image = $("<img  id='slideShowImage' src='" + _url + "'/>");
                            $(_link).append(_Image);
                            _slideDiv.append(_link);

                            _Title = $("<div class='caption'><p>" + _title + "</p></div>");
                            _slideDiv.append(_Title);

                _Description = $("<p>" + _description + "</p>");
                            _slideDiv.append(_Description);

                            $(".slides_container").append(_slideDiv);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: where is click event function?is this sample code?bcoz ur calling this function in document. ready.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the below line,

```
  completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
```

instead of this,

```
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    var hasRows = false;
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function   () {
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, `a`-tags does not use the `src` attribute as you have used, but the `href` attribute. So replace

```
$("<a  src='" + _url + "'/>");
```

with

```
$("<a  href='" + _url + "'/>");
```

(By the way, `a`-tags is not self closing so I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish?)

You also seem to use the same `_url` variable as both the source of the image tag and to the link, so please make sure you use the correct variables